# POST request from AngularJS controller to Spring controller

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

I'm posting parts of my code, since it's alot, but what I want to do is on click on button "REMOVE", send the current value from the "extensions" div from my typescript controller to the java controller using a POST request. My code:

controlbarView.html

```
  <div class="perspectives">
     <div class="button" data-color="black">
        <button ng-click="perspectivesMode()"> EDIT MODE </button>
     </div>
     <div>
        <button ng-click="removeElement()"> REMOVE CURRENT </button>
     </div>
  </div>

  <div class="settings">

     <div class="extensions" style="height: 50px; width: 400px;" ng-repeat="ext in extensions track by $index" ng-if="$last">
        {{ext}}
     </div>

     <div class="extensionsNavi" style="height: 50px; width: 400px;" ng-repeat="ext in extensionsNavi track by $index" ng-if="$last">
        {{ext}}
     </div>
```

controlbarViewController.ts

```
 //for Shortcuts page - don't navigate to shortcuts page on click.
         $scope.perspectivesMode = function(){
           console.log("We're in perspectives mode");
           perspectivesService.setProperty(true);
           //console.log(navigationTreeService.getExtensions);
         };
         //Show extensions from shortcuts page
         $scope.extensions = perspectivesService.getExtension();
         //Show extensions from main pages
         $scope.extensionsNavi = navigationTreeService.getExtensions();

         //on click - add extension to file with extensions to remove
         $scope.removeElement = function(){
            var removeExt = $scope.extensions;
            $http({
               method: 'POST',
               url: 'remove',
               params: { removeExt: removeExt
                        }
            });
         };
```

extensionsController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/remove", method = Request.POST)

   public String getExtensionToRemove(){
      @RequestParam(value = "removeExt", required=false);
      return ext;
   }
```

How can I modify my java controller so that I obtain and return the removeExt and then use it in another java class?